# CSS rotate divs 100% width

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have a design with stacked divs, where the inner divs will have various skews and rotations.  Doing some initial testing, quite logically the rotated divs leave gaps on the edges rather than being flush 100%.  Here's a crude example: [image]

What's the best way to fill these gaps and have them work tightly responsively?  My initial thought is to add other skewed divs to fill in the spaces, but wondering if there are better methods?  Thanks.

Comment: without your css hard to say, did you reset transform-origin ? defaut axis is from the center of the element

Answer (score 2):

Without a working code sample, it's hard to give you precise advice, but in general, you just increase the width of the rotated element and potentially offset it to the right or left depending on how you have positioned it.

```css
div {
  background: black;
  height: 100px; width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  height: 10px;
  width: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: -25%;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know why that didn't occur to me.  I guess overflow hidden is the next step to keep from horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @AmandaK yes, overflow is the last step. example from my comment (using padding to increase width so content should remain on sight ) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BpKKxe  skew is also another approach http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KazzxV